# how can we capture all the values using regular expression extractor and json path extractor in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, blazemeter

how can we capture all the values in a variable using regular expression extractor and json path extractor in jmeter?
I have tried with match no = -1 but its not giving any value.

Comment: add the screenshot of JSON Path extractor, partial response and what you wants to extract from it.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENxHd.png)

First image is the response data value which we want to capture in single time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clNFP.png)
This is the regular expression to extract the "text"value .